# FHIR: how to customize identifier element

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am trying to convert customized data format into FHIR standard. In my example, we have a practitioner (physician) with certain unique id defined by hospital. This unique id is hospital specific, not like NPI or SSN.

My approach is to use identifier element in Practitioner resource where it has system and code. For NPI or SSN, I can add value as is and set identifier.system to associated url. However, for unique id, I am not sure how to define it besides setting value to unique id. Is it possible to create url (system) that meets whatever I need?

Answer (score 1):

The rules for system are [here](https://hl7.org/fhir/datatypes.html#Identifier). If you are setting up a FHIR server, then you can define the system that client systems should use for that type of identifier. If you are trying to pass this data to a FHIR server owned/governed by someone else, you would need to understand if that FHIR server can accept values with any system or if there are prescribed ones that are accepted.